# How to apply more than one conditional style to elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a div that looks like this

```
<div v-for="person in people">
    <p class='name' :class="{people.age == "adult" : 'green'}"></p>
</div>
```

I can change the class like that, but I have many age groups (around 8) and I am not sure how this can be done, without putting 8 logical arguments inside the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a computed property like this:

```
computed: {
    computedPeople: function(){
        return this.people.map(function(person){
            person.cls = {
                green: person.age == "adult",
                //otherClass: otherCondition ...
                //...
                //...
            };
        });
    }
},
```

then

```
<div v-for="person in computedPeople">
    <p class='name' :class="person.cls"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's bad practice to have a class called `green` - what happens one day when you redesign the site and suddenly what was once green is now blue.. you would have to go back and change the names of all the classes in the templates, and then go and change all the CSS as well.

It's much better practice to have a class called `adult`, and then actually set the color of `adult` in the CSS to "green".

Further to that, you should put the logic determining what group they fall into on the `person` model. So that you can simply call `person.age_group` (for example) and that would return the string `adult` which would then be mapped to whatever color you want).

That way, not only do you not have a big conditional block in your template, your other bits of code can call the same function and determine the "type" of user (adult/child etc)